# Has there been an experiment with entangled particles to observe effect on decay time when one is at relativistic speed?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, quantum-entanglement, accelerator-physics, proton-decay

Has there been an experiment with entangled particles, two of the same, for example two neutrons, where one is left mostly at rest and the other accelerated to relativistic speed to observe if any effect on decay time from entanglement occurs?

I know there will be a difference in time due to time dilation for the relativistic particle so when I say difference in time I mean with that accounted for.

Also, I know this is jumbling two unrelated things, entanglement and decay where entanglement requires nothing from the 'clocks' of the particles and is just a statistical effect to the observables of the particles. Which makes this a seemingly benign and useless rock to look under in the first place but nonetheless I guess I'm wondering if the useless rock has been looked under (even if unintentionally) and if so (awesome) was there any effect? Or if you have nothing for this specific scenario is there any research that shows effects on decay time of entangled particles vs it's non-entangled? Also can you provide source of any research? Thank you!!

Comment: Entanglement does not affect decay time, nor does acceleration. Time dilation is an effect of relative speed, not of acceleration.

Comment: Right, "accelerated to relativistic speed" and "Also, I know this is jumbling two unrelated things, entanglement and decay where ..."

Comment: If you knew the answer then why did you ask?

Comment: Oh no no I don't know the answer, I'm asking if something has ever been done and then I'm just explaining foundational understanding in hopes of helping others not waste time giving a special relativity course, for example. But in physics just because we know theoretical dependencies or lack of dependencies doesn't mean we don't test to prove or disprove, so my question is asking if this has ever been conducted while agreeing, yes if we look at a physics textbook it looks grim for lack of connection.

Comment: For example here's an experiment that's saying "hey is there a flaw in what we know about general relativity", the answer was 'nothing new': https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.pri.org/stories/2015-12-21/how-mis-launched-satellite-might-help-us-test-einsteins-theory-general-relativity%3famp

Comment: Would you mind removing the down vote, it seems there was just misunderstanding in what's being asked, I'd be more than happy to edit to make it clearer if you have feedback

Comment: you need to edit it, otherwise the vote is locked

Comment: Has there ever been an experiment to test whether jumping on a bed can make the sun explode?  There has not, for these reasons:  1)  There is absolutely no reason to expect such a thing; 2)  Well established physics gives good reasons to expect the opposite; and 3) there is no end to the number of random unmotivated experiments one can concoct, but it's generally considered more useful to devote one's resources to experiments we have some reasonable hope of learning something from.  All of which applies equally here.

Comment: WillO, youre right, I forgot we already know everything about physics and stopped researching years ago, of course! around the same time we finished GUT! If only I had some analogy with a cat and a both decayed /nondecayed isotope to draw some correlation with. Or if only coherent collective phenomena was a close sibling of quantum entanglement or if coherence between multiple particles could cause enhanced decay rates and was even an observed phenomenon in superradiance. Yes indeed, a fool jumping on a bed trying to make the sun explode.Or maybe when you know everything, you learn nothing new

Comment: Seriously, now, the point is not an issue of knowing everything, but there are *some* things known  better than others: not every random bet is as good as a sensible one. Time dilation is a special relativistic effect not suspected to mesh with quantum coherence, and likewise for decay mechanisms of particles.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer this:

> for example two neutrons, where one is left mostly at rest and the other *accelerated* to relativistic speed to observe if any effect on decay time from entanglement occurs?

italics mine

Entanglement and decay are quantum mechanical phenomena and need the mathematics of quantum mechanics. This means that only probability distributions can be checked, i.e. doing the experiment many times with the exact boundary conditions.

When the neutrons are entangled they have to be in the same inertial frame to have **one** wavefunction describing the entangled system.

When one of them is accelerated  the entanglement is broken, because in order to accelerate a particle an **interaction has to happen** which means one no longer has the same one wavefunction, a different one describes each neutron,also they are in different inertial frames. One cannot set up an experiment with the same boundary conditions so that the probabilistic distributions of the decay of the second could be connected to the first neutron. The distributions will be random by the definitions of quantum mechanics.

As entanglement is part of the quantum framework , if one ignores quantum mechanics, there is no way to set up the experiment anyway. That is what the comments are trying to say.

Comment: Pompous code words for “an interaction has to happen” are “coherence has been spoilt”…